# Silverstripe 4 - Add many_many relationship by default

Tags: silverstripe-4

Is it possible to have a many_many relationship added by default?

I am working with the subsites module where each site has a Blog, but we want the ability to tag BlogPosts so they can appear on any of the other subsites:

- subsite 1
- subsite 2
- subsite 3

I have this setup as an extension to BlogPost:

```
private static $many_many = [
        'Subsites' => Subsite::class       
    ];

$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.PostOptions', 
            TagField::create('Subsites','Show on other sites',Subsite::get(),$this->owner->Subsites())
                ->setShouldLazyLoad(false) 
                ->setCanCreate(false) 
            );
```

How would I add the current subsite as a default relation on creation of the BlogPost, so that each BlogPost under Subsite2 has a 'Subsite2' tag by default, ie using

```
Subsite::get_by_id(SubsiteState::singleton()->getSubsiteId())
```

If that doesn't make sense I'll try and explain more :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the relations in your BlogPost's `onBeforeWrite` function, this would work by simply calling `$this->Subsites()->add($subsiteObject)`. To make sure that the Object was really created and not only updated, you can check for the objects id. If it has none yet, the object was newly created.